# Plain text to Html tagged pretty text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have searched for at JavaScript to prettify a plain text from a textarea to html5 text string with JavaScript/AngularJs. No luck, so I hope someone in here has a good example to start out with?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need to use something like [Prism](http://prismjs.com). It's [extensibly used](http://prismjs.com/#used-by) and created by the amazing [Lea Verou](https://twitter.com/LeaVerou). There's also an npm package for Angular (2 or higher), [angular-prism](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-prism).

Another alternative is [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org) with its own npm package for Angular as well [angular-highlightjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highlightjs)

Comment: Im not looking for at syntax highlighter, but a script to formatting plain text to a pretty html text whit ex. <h2> tags, <p> tags <br> etc.

Comment: Can you provide an example with a plain text input and the desired output?

Comment: Input: She was born in NYC. This is the body text, and her name was..
Output: <h4>She was born in NYC.&nbsp;</h4>
<p><br></p>
<p>This is the body text, and her name was</p>

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are looking for. How the script will know where to open a tag and where to close it?

Comment: Im looking for a JavaScript to formatting and prettify a written text. Adding the html tags required for doing that with ex. <h4> and <p> etc.